# What's (by default) on the classpath when you run a Jenkins job?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, classpath

When you kick off a maven test in Jenkins, what is Jenkins putting onto the Java classpath by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it would be system's classpath (jdk you specified) and maven dependencies available to test phase

You can verify it by adding

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
```

Comment: OK, now I have a follow-up question on that: [Is there an official document from the maven project that tells you what's on the classpath for each goal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24412796/what-classpath-does-maven-set-can-you-provide-a-link-to-official-docs)

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope dependency scope controlls the accessiblity of dependencies in phases

Comment: For goal `test`, it seems to be /target/test-classes, target/classes and the dependencies from the local repositories folder.