# What classpath does maven set for different goals? Can you provide a link to official docs?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, classpath, maven-3

To what does Maven set the classpath for different goals?

My issue: I have a project that I am building in Jenkins. It gets checked out form SVN. As the next thing, a different file is checked out into `workspace-root/mydir/my.properties`

Then, `maven test` is run.

In the test, a class loads the file by searching it on the classpath. Why does that work?
(I'm new to Jenkins and maven and am trying to figure out how the job I'm looking at works...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven uses the `<dependencies/>` defined in your project as puts them on the classpath of the plugins. Furthermore, in the `<plugin/>` section of each plugin, you can define additional `<dependencies/>` which are only to be used by the plugin (and will therefore not become part of the final artifact in any way, or visible on the `mvn dependency:tree`).

In regards to the tests, it's important to know that:

- Resources under `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources` are respectively copied to `target/classes` and `target/test-classes`. These two directories are added to your classpath. (The same is valid for `src/main/java` and `src/test/java`).
- Each Maven plugin is executed in it's own classloader.
- When executing tests, the `maven-surefire-plugin` will usually fork your tests into a separate classloader.

Check [this](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-maven-classloading.html) link.

Answer (score 0):

> a class loads the file by searching it on the classpath. Why does that work?

Because this is what maven is designed to do.  It knows your dependencies, because you set them and makes assumptions about the structure of the modules you are building e.g. src/main/resources will be added and it add all these to the class path.

Comment: The only thing is, my workspace looks like this: /mydir, /src, /target, /pom.xml. Now, I remember having red somewhere that maven puts your code and dependencies (i.e. /src and the repository folder) on the classpath (do you have a link to the docs for that, by any chance? I couldn't find it on the official website by searching for "classpath), but it doesn't explain how /mydir ended up there...

Comment: @Christian It doesn't add `/src` or the others you mention but it will compile `/src/main/java` and add everything compiled into the class path.

Comment: Following advice from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24412637/2018047), I echoed out the classpath when the test runs: For goal `test`, it seems to add /target/test-classes, target/classes and the dependencies from the local repositories folder. So, still no clue how /mydir made it in there... :(

Comment: @Christian Agreed unless it is mentioned in the pom, or added by a plugin, it shouldn't be there.

Comment: Ouch. I just realized I took the wrong turn somewhere in the source code. Apparently, the code uses Spring's  org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource()... Sorry for having tomatoes on my eyes...

Comment: So, that method uses java.io.File, and that class uses the current user directory to resolve current paths, which is accessible through `user.dir`. On Jenkins, that turns out to be the `workspace-root` on Jenkins, but the project's root (e.g. `trunk`) on local when running maven - at least for me... so, by looking for `mydir/my.properties`, it gets loaded in on Jenkins. My guess is that Jenkins actually sets the current user directory. Now, the only thing still missing in my puzzle is a link to the official docs' relevant part... :)

Comment: Just a clarification: `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources` are not added to the classpath. What really happens is that the resources underneath those two directories are copied (respectively) to `target/classes` and `target/test-classes`. These two directories are the actual ones which are placed on the classpath.